# Folder Structure In SSIS for Output file and naming convention of Output file

Tags: ssis

**SSIS**

This is **general question** which i am going to ask and might **possible to have multiple answer.**

Techie, please share with me the best solution if familiar with scenario.

i have 100 customer and they share file for us to load into our database.
and after compution and the output file need to be saved in Output folder.

the name of the output file should be customer_name.txt where customer_name
is coming from a column available in input file.

Can anyone please help me how should i design this in **SSIS** to achieve my Goal

Comment: may anyone please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, use a Foreach Loop Container for every file.
For each one, store data into your importTable in database with the fileName or customerName.

Then, when you need to get output file:
Get the nameFile or userName with a query and save it into a ssis variable. 
Create your file with the 'DestinationVariable' as 'User::yourVariableName'

Add the data from your database and then use a simple script to move it into output folder

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DdZWM.png)